# Как задать доступ к определённой странице, если у пользователя в столбце type = значение «3»?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как задать доступ к определённой странице (контенту), если у пользователя в столбце type = значение «3», а если «1» или «2» — редирект?

Пример: просто проверка на зарегистрированного пользователя

```
<?php if ( isset ($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?>
```

Comment: я не уверен что угадал с расположением type, потмоу что вы не привели принт массива юзера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.super-margin {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>

<?php
$class = '';

if ((int)$_SESSION['logged_user']['type'] === 3) {
    $class = ' super-margin';
} else {
    header('Location: redirect-to',true, 301);
}
?>

<div class="content<?php echo $class;?>">
контент
</div>
```

классу задаем нужный отступ и добавляем этот класс к нужному элементу. я надеюсь что отступ нужно задать в том же файле где и делается редирект. Если нет, то вместо переменной *$class* используйте куку или ту же сессию.

Функция header в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

Comment: Сработало. Вот только где контент писать?

Comment: И для чего $class = 'super-margin'; я так и не понял

Comment: задаете в css для класса super-margin отступ нужны и потом выводите этот класс для элемента который должен получить этот отступ. Обновил ответ